# TextTransform.exe - how to pass $(TargetDir), when running from cmd?

Tags: batch-file, t4

I have a script called dtos.tt with the following:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)WW.XX.API.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)WW.XX.Model.dll" #>
bla bla
```

And the script is working fine, when "running custom tool" inside VS2019. But I wish to do this through a .bat file.

But when I do that, I get the following error:

> error : An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Repos\XX\XX\XX.XX.WebSite\common$(TargetDir)XX.XX.API.dll'.

Here is the content of my .bat file:

```
ECHO OFF
cd C:\Repos\XX\XX\XX.XX.WebSite\common
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe" C:\Repos\XX\XX\XX.XX.WebSite\common\dtos.tt    
PAUSE
```

What can I do to make the TextTransform.exe know about my ($TargetDir) ?

Comment: add an [ItemGroup which sets the values](https://thomaslevesque.com/2017/11/13/transform-t4-templates-as-part-of-the-build-and-pass-variables-from-the-project/)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I need the same thing.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - Nope sorry :/